# Php upload docx and pdf files

Tags: php, sql, file, upload, directory

I already used this code to upload images and it worked, but now I have tried changing it to upload docx and pdf, but it is always giving error only docx and pdf files, it can not check the extension of docx and pdf like jpg, png, etc...? 
Sorry my English.

```
<?php   
extract($_POST);

$UploadedFileName=$_FILES['UploadImage']['name']['nome'];
if($UploadedFileName!='') {
  $upload_directory = "../../../documentos/formularios/"; 
  $nome=$_POST['nome'];
  $TargetPath=time().$UploadedFileName;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($TargetPath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $ficheirogrande='<div class="alert alert-danger">O Ficheiro ultrapassa <strong>2 Megas</strong></div>';   
  $preenchimentoobrigadorio='<div class="alert alert-danger">Campo <strong>nome</strong> de preenchimento obrigatório</div>';   
  $apenasficheiros='<div class="alert alert-danger">Apenas Ficheiros <strong>PDF e DOCX</strong> podem ser inseridos</div>';

  if(empty($_POST['nome']) || false === filter_var($_POST['nome'])){
    echo $preenchimentoobrigadorio; 
  } else {
    if ($_FILES["UploadImage"]["size"] > 2200000){ //2.09808
      echo $ficheirogrande;
    } else {
      if($imageFileType != "application/msword" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ){
        echo $apenasficheiros;
      } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadImage']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$TargetPath)){
          $caminho="documentos/formularios/$TargetPath"; 
          $queryinserir="INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS(LINK_DOCUMENTOS,NOME,FORMULARIOS) VALUES ('$caminho','$nome','1')";

          mysqli_query($conn,$queryinserir); 

          $enviado='<div class="alert alert-success">Documento Inserido com <strong>Sucesso</strong></div>';
          echo $enviado;    
        } else {    
          $naoenviado='<div class="alert alert-danger">Documento <strong>Nao Inserido</strong></div>';
          echo $naoenviado;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$_FILES['UploadImage']['name']['nome']`?! Don't you get error at this line?! And `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` will only return file extention, So you will probably never have `application/msword` as a file extension. Also at this line `if($imageFileType != "application/msword" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ){` You should use `||` instead of `&&` otherwise it will always return false and that's the reason you are always getting the error...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the new file at `$targetPath`, so the file does not exist and you can not get the extension

Also, using the extension is not a safe method. You should use the MIME type.